# Pygame window closes right after

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1100, 600
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

def main():
    run = True
    while run:        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
    
        WIN.fill(WHITE)
        pygame.display.update()
    
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__GAME!__":
    main()
```

When I run this code, the pygame window closes right after while using Virtual Studio Code. While using Jupyter notebook it runs but goes unresponsive after 2-3 seconds. Both of them do not display any errors though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using

`if __name__ == "__GAME!__"`

But if I change this to

`if __name__ == "__main__"`

Then it works.

Comment: Would be good to explain why this is needed (or link to some resource). I.e. that `__name__` is a special variable that describe the file's name, and that when it equals `"__main__"` it means that the file being run is the entry point of the program.